# How to insert date only from pandas dataframe to postgres

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, datetime

I am trying to insert a pandas dataframe with a date column into a Postgres database such that the data type in Postgres is also a date ('YYYY-MM-DD') but i can only get it to insert at `timestamp without a timezone` rather than a `date`. How can I do this?

Here's some starter code (though you'll need postgres creds to connect and test for real):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

# create toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-02-01', '2022-03-11']})
df['date']=df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d'))

# connect to postgres
sqlalchemy.create_engine(secrets.get(**SECRETS)))

# insert df into postgres
df.to_sql(
    "toy_table",
    engine,
    schema="toy_schema",
    index=False)
```

Comment: What is the data type for the field in the Postgres table? If it is `timestamp` then you will get a timestamp. If you want only a date stored then use the `date` type per [Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as described, the pandas dates get auto-converted to `text` in postgres despite their python data type being a date

Comment: The question remains, what is the data type for the field in `toy_table`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver and the answer remains, it is a pandas datetime64 (i've stripped the time component such that it's just YYYY-MM-DD but it's still a pandas datetime

Comment: Yes, but the issue is when you insert it into the Postgres database. What you see is going to depend on the data type of the field you are inserting into. Until you provide that information an answer to your question is not possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have already tried inserting a pandas column of python `datetime.date` objects? If so, can you please update the example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate what I am talking about in my comments, that you need to make the field a `date`:

```
\d dt_test 
                         Table "public.dt_test"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id       | integer                     |           |          | 
 ts_fld   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 tsz_fld  | timestamp with time zone    |           |          | 
 date_fld | date                        |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "t_idx" btree ((ts_fld::date))

insert into dt_test values 
    (1, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01'), 
    (2, '2022-03-11', '2022-03-11', '2022-03-11');

select * from dt_test ;
 id |       ts_fld        |        tsz_fld         |  date_fld  
----+---------------------+------------------------+------------
  1 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00-08 | 2022-02-01
  2 | 2022-03-11 00:00:00 | 2022-03-11 00:00:00-08 | 2022-03-11
```

A `timestamp(tz)` field is always going to have a time component. When you supply just a `date` the value will have `00:00:00` added to it to make it a timestamp.

Comment: Right and what I was trying to communicate is how to insert a python 'date'-like data type directly intk postgres so it is automatically interpreted as a postgres `date`. I can get it to be a timestamp (w/ or w/out TZ)

Comment: This `2022-02-01 00:00:00` is a `date` when you do `select '2022-02-01 00:00:00'::date; 2022-02-01`. If you want to store it directly as a `date` only then the Postgres field/column needs to be of type `date`.

Comment: Yeah that's basically the solution i found. Create the table first setting constraints/data types then insert from pandas and it will be coerced correctly to match. If you add that info to your answer, i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Answer updated per request.